# c# Doesn't read all content from socket in local http server

Tags: c#, sockets, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm using a local server in a Windows Store App (http://blog.jsolutions.co.uk/?p=492) for serve html files.

The program reads the input from socket:

```
    StringBuilder inputRequestBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // Read all the request data.
    // (This is assuming it is all text data of course)
    using (var input = socket.InputStream)
    {
        var data = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(BUFFER_SIZE);
        uint dataRead = BUFFER_SIZE;

        while (dataRead == BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            await input.ReadAsync(data, BUFFER_SIZE, InputStreamOptions.Partial);

            var dataArray = data.ToArray();
            var dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);

            inputRequestBuilder.Append(dataString);
            dataRead = data.Length;
        }
    }
```

But sometimes, when the user submit a html form, the inputRequestBuilder has not all the content, for example:

```
"POST /LMS/ajax.php?op=commitSCORM HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nReferer: http://localhost:8080/xxxxxxx.htm\r\nAccept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; WebView/1.0)\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nContent-Length: 2537\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nCookie: port=8080\r\n\r\n"
```

The content-length is 2537, but there is no content. So, I don't know what's the problem. Maybe the webview sends two packet (http header and form content) and... I don't know.

I tried to read from socket again, when all the content is not ready, but VS throws: Error 0x80072746 The remote host closed the connection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `InputStreamOptions.Partial` to `ReadAsync`. This implies that `ReadAsync` may return with less than `BUFFER_SIZE` even when there is more data in the wire.

Try using `InputStreamOptions.None` instead. But this may not work in your case, because the connection will remain open and ReadAsync will block. You will need to parse the `Content-Length` value from the headers, and read that amount of bytes after the `\r\n\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

With the comment of Kiewic, the ugly script that works:

```
StringBuilder inputRequestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
List<byte> last4bytes = new List<byte>();
string request = null;
using (var input = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())
{
    int b;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            b = input.ReadByte();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            FileManager.WriteToDebug(e.ToString());
            break;
        }
        bytes.Add((byte)b);
        if (last4bytes.Count < 4)
        {
            last4bytes.Add((byte)b);
        }
        else
        {
            last4bytes.RemoveAt(0);
            last4bytes.Add((byte)b);
            if (last4bytes.ElementAt(0) == 13 && last4bytes.ElementAt(1) == 10
                && last4bytes.ElementAt(2) == 13 && last4bytes.ElementAt(3) == 10)
            {
                //after \r\n\r\n there is the content
                byte[] byteArray = bytes.ToArray();
                request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                inputRequestBuilder.Append(request);
                string contentLength = getValueFromHeader("Content-Length", request);
                if (!contentLength.Equals(""))
                {
                    int length = Convert.ToInt32(contentLength);
                    if (length > 0)
                    {
                        byteArray = new byte[length];
                        input.Read(byteArray, 0, length);
                        var dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                        inputRequestBuilder.Append(dataString);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
request = inputRequestBuilder.ToString();
```